# PHP MySQL wrong code

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to learn PHP, so I'm doing this by creating scripts and building sites.

Here's my code to check a server ID.

```
<?php
    include('configuration/mysql.php');
    include('php/functions.php');
?>
<?php
    function canList($email1, $id) {
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Panel_Servers WHERE ID = '$id'") or die (mysql_error());
        while($sv=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            if($id == $sv['ID']) {
                echo 'working.';
            }
        }
    }
    canList("sawickas2@gmail.com", "2740");
?>
```

SQL connection is good, working. Query is working too, tested on phpmyadmin sql (without variable), ID column equals 2740 too.

I tried many options, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: is your id column really uppercase? @Khushboo no, it has echo inside te function

Comment: According to your script, if($id == $sv['ID']) {  echo 'working.';    }...... when that condition is not met, your script will exit silently

Comment: add exit; when your condition match.

Comment: Check first whether your $query have required value or not by using print_r($query);

Comment: Make sure `$id` cannot come from user input, because there is no protection from SQL injection here. OP, look into parameterisation in MySQLi when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copy your code and run on my local machine and it's working like a charm, now I paste my working code here:

```
<?php

function canList($email1, $id) {
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jtw");
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sample WHERE id = '".$id."'") or die (mysql_error());
    while($sv=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        if($id == $sv['id']) {
            echo 'working.';
            echo $id;
        }
    }
}
canList("sawickas2@gmail.com", "1");
 ?>
```

I've changed your `id` column to lower case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to tell `mysql_fetch_array` what type of data you want returned. By default it returns a array with numerical keys, so your `$sv` array data would have been in `$sv[0]`. Just pass in the `MYSQL_ASSOC` optional second parameter into `mysql_fetch_array` like so;

```
<?php
    include('configuration/mysql.php');
    include('php/functions.php');
?>
<?php
    function canList($email1, $id) {
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Panel_Servers WHERE ID = '$id'") or die (mysql_error());
        while($sv=mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            if($id == $sv['ID']) {
                echo 'working.';
            }
        }
    }
    canList("sawickas2@gmail.com", "2740");
?>
```

Now your array index should be keys of `ID`, such as `$sv['ID']`.